# Up navigation not appearing, when opening Fragments not in runtime

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-navigation, up-navigation

The application consists of 1 `Activity` with a `NavigationDrawer` and we can open `Fragment`s in a 2 level hierarchy also. In the latter case, we have a `Back Button` on the `ActionBar` to implement up navigation.
Everything works fine at runtime, if we open the fragments in the 2 level hierarchy by click events, but when we do the same from code - with also the same code -, the navigation button won't show up. The navigation still works. If we navigate back to the home level, the `NavigationBar`'s hamburger icon show up, and if we open the `Fragment`s in the 2 level hierarchy by click events, then the back button show up instead of the hamburger icon as it should.
In short: everything works fine again, if we navigate back to the home level.

The related methods:

```
private void shouldDisplayHomeAsUp() {
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  boolean shouldDisplay = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0;
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
  if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(shouldDisplay);
    CharSequence actionBarTitle = actionBar.getTitle();
    if (isMainListFragment(shouldDisplay, actionBarTitle)) {
      actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
      setDrawerEnabled(true);
    }
  }
}

private void setDrawerEnabled(boolean enabled) {
  if (!enabled) {
    disableDrawer();
    enableActionBarBackNavigation();
  } else {
    enableDrawer();
  }
}

private void disableDrawer() {
  drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
  actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
  actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

private void enableDrawer() {
  drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
  actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
  actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

private void enableActionBarBackNavigation() {
  actionBarDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      onBackPressed();
    }

  });
}
```

The `shouldDisplayHomeAsUp()` method called by the `onBackStackChanged()`, but there is no difference, when we call it in a static manner.
Mostly we call the `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` and 
`actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)` methods.

See the below pictures:
[image: left is the proper one]

If we set a reminder in the application, it will trigger a notification. When we click on the notification, it open the main screen - home level -, the a list - as You can see above -, and then a detaild view of notification related todo. Then we can navigate back in the view hierarchy. That is the purpose to open the fragments programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
Modified the method like this:

```
private void shouldDisplayHomeAsUp() {
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  boolean shouldDisplay = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0;
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
  if (actionBar != null) {
    if (shouldDisplay) {
      setDrawerEnabled(false);
      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    } else {
      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
      setDrawerEnabled(true);
    }

    CharSequence actionBarTitle = actionBar.getTitle();
    if (isMainListFragment(shouldDisplay, actionBarTitle)) {
      actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
      setDrawerEnabled(true);
    }
  }
}
```

The order of `setDrawerEnabled(false)` and `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` method calls are very important. That was the root cause of the problem.